# List-to-Vector C++/CLI Conversion Function (left of '::' must be a class/struct/union)

Tags: c#, c++, templates, generics, c++-cli

I have these dummy C++ classes, which I want to expose in C#:

```cpp
// include/my_lib/Container.hpp
#pragma once

#include <vector>

namespace my_cpp
{
    struct EntryOne
    {
        EntryOne(double value)
            : value(value) { }

        double value;
    };

    struct EntryTwo
    {
          EntryTwo(char digit)
            : digit(digit) { }

          char digit;
    };

    struct Container
    {
        Container(const std::vector<EntryOne>& entriesOne, const std::vector<EntryTwo>& entriesTwo)
            : entriesOne(entriesOne), entriesTwo(entriesTwo) { }

        std::vector<EntryOne> entriesOne;
        std::vector<EntryTwo> entriesTwo;
    };
}
```

So I wrap them via CLI as follows:

```cpp
// include/my_lib_cli/ContainerCLI.hpp
#pragma once

#include <my_lib/Container.hpp>

using namespace System;
using namespace System::Collections::Generic;

namespace MyCLI
{
    template<class T>
    public ref class ManagedObject
    {
    public:
        using NativeType = T;          // <-- Note that I expose the underlying type here!

        ManagedObject(T* nativePtr)
            : nativePtr(nativePtr) { }

        virtual ~ManagedObject() {
            this->!ManagedObject();
        }

        !ManagedObject() {
            if (nativePtr != nullptr)
                delete nativePtr;
        }

        T* nativePtr;
    };

    public ref class EntryOneCLI : public ManagedObject<my_cpp::EntryOne>
    {
    public:
        EntryOneCLI(double value);
    };

    public ref class EntryTwoCLI : public ManagedObject<my_cpp::EntryTwo>
    {
    public:
        EntryTwoCLI(char digit);
    };

    public ref class ContainerCLI : public ManagedObject<my_cpp::Container>
    {
    public:
        ContainerCLI(List<EntryOneCLI^>^ entriesOne, List<EntryTwoCLI^>^ entriesTwo);
    };
}
```

```cpp
// src/my_lib_cli/ContainerCLI.cpp
#include <my_lib_cli/ContainerCLI.hpp>

namespace MyCLI
{
    EntryOneCLI::EntryOneCLI(double value)
        : ManagedObject(new my_cpp::EntryOne(value)) { }

    EntryTwoCLI::EntryTwoCLI(char digit)
        : ManagedObject(new my_cpp::EntryTwo(digit)) { }

    ContainerCLI::ContainerCLI(List<EntryOneCLI^>^ entriesOne, List<EntryTwoCLI^>^ entriesTwo)
        : ManagedObject(new my_cpp::Container(to_cpp(entriesOne), to_cpp(entriesTwo))) { }
}
```

For ease of use, I tried to write a `to_cpp` function that converts any C# `List` to a C++ `std::vector`. Using the `T::NativeType` type information (which is known at compile time) to derive the C++ vector element type:

```cpp
    template<class T>
    static decltype(auto) to_cpp(System::Collections::Generic::List<T>^ lst)
    {
        std::vector<T::NativeType> vec;
        vec.reserve(lst->Count);

        for each (T element in lst)
            vec.emplace_back(*element->nativePtr);

        return vec;
    }
```

Unfortunately, this results in multiple errors:

```
ContainerCLI.hpp(56,21): error C2825: 'T': must be a class or namespace when followed by '::'
ContainerCLI.hpp(56,24): error C2510: 'T': left of '::' must be a class/struct/union
ContainerCLI.hpp(56, 1): error C2065: 'NativeType': undeclared identifier
ContainerCLI.hpp(56,14): error C2923: 'std::vector': 'NativeType' is not a valid template type argument for parameter '_Ty'
ContainerCLI.hpp(56,14): error C2976: 'std::vector': too few template arguments
```

Is there a way to fix this and write a generic `to_cpp` conversion function, using the `NativeType` type information?

Comment: `std::vector<T::NativeType>` needs to be `std::vector<typename T::NativeType>` (this would be true in native code as well).  Can't tell if there are other errors.

Comment: @BenVoigt Unfortunately, whether I use `typename` or not, gives the same list of errors as above, e.g. `error C2510: 'T': left of '::' must be a class/struct/union`.

Comment: These errors are all coming from the `std::vector<T::NativeType> vec;` line correct?

Comment: Does the compiler output (not necessarily inside an "error message") tell you what `T` is inferred to?  It's probably `EntryOneCLI^` which is a handle type, not a class type.  You may need to write the C++/CLI version of `std::remove_reference`.

Comment: To illustrate, this wouldn't work in native code either: `struct S { using Y = int; }; using T = S*; typename T::Y y = 0;`  Because `S` has a member typedef `Y` but `S*` does not.

Comment: @BenVoigt There is no statement that explicitly states what `T` is, but it says `ContainerCLI.cpp(12,47): message : see reference to function template instantiation 'decltype(auto) to_cpp<EntryOneCLI^>(List<EntryOneCLI ^> ^)' being compiled`. See https://pastebin.com/Xb88qwhe for full output. So you may be right about `T = EntryOneCLI^`. So I tried using `std::remove_reference`, `std::decay`, etc. but no luck. Is there a C#/CLI equivalent of type traits as there is in C++?

Comment: It should be pretty straightforward to build a C++/CLI version of `std::remove_reference`, say `template <typename T> struct remove_tracking_reference { using type = T; }; template <typename T> struct remove_tracking_reference<T^> { using type = T; };`